# Gives error while i am posting a blog on wordpress CMS

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress CMS and when i am post a new post by using "/wp-admin/post-new.php" page it gives me an error page while i am using "save draft" or "publish" used. Error page redirect to same page "/wp-admin/post.php" and in page content it shows

```
Not Found
Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found. Perhaps searching will help.
```

this error occurs while i am posting a new post relate to SQL.

I think it generates by SQL injections but how can i prevent my blog site by using SQL injections like this.

It gives me error while i am using always select, insert, update, delete keywords used. How can i prevent this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to many different things. Have you tried deactivating plugins and your current theme?

Wordpress itself should be able to handle a post about SQL statements. Maybe you have some characters within your post that wordpress cannot cope with lick in this Case: [Cannot publish new post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-publish-new-posts-post-not-found)

If those steps do not help you I guess your best shot at a quick solution is to post your question at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ since it's a wordpress related issue.